# Suggestions for ASP.NET Website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on big application build using ASP.NET which was started 1.5 years back. The Site uses 3rd party telerik RadControls for UI. The problem with the website is it uses outdated stuffs like DataSets and all with no proper architecture. I have done some research and found some new technologies like ADO.NET Entity Framework out here. I want to know that is it worth investing to learn and migrate my site to ADO.NET Entity Framework at this stage.

Additionally are there any good technologies or tools (that can be used in ASP.NET) out there in the market which can be used to make the development life easier and be upto date with latest technologies.

ALL SUGGESTIONS WOULD BE REALLY PRECIOUS.

THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Comment: its always worth investing to learn new things. Never stop learning

Comment: It depends really on what you need and what the website is doing. You shouldn't pick technologies just because they are cool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real answer to this question.

Entity Framework is very useful. As is ASP.NET MVC. I guess it depends on what your metrics are to determine if it is worth it.

What are the goals for migration? Are you looking for a more testable website? Its unlikely to be worth migrating a large website just for the sake of it, so determining the measure of a successful migration may naturally lead you to a decision.

Its also worth noting that ASP.NET Web forms are still a viable option. If you want rapid development, which uses data grids and such like, then forms might be your best option. You could look to move to MVC, which will allow you to enforce a cleaner separation of concerns. Its horses for courses. A quick Google and you will find plenty of forms vs mvc pros and cons.

You could also consider a piece meal migration. For example, you could build and Entity Framework model of your database and start to use it one page at a time. Slowly removing ADO, but maintaining a working site. You can also use Forms, and MVC together in one site. So you don't have to do a complete migration in one go.

Food for thought, good luck.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, it would be a better option to gradually migrate along with developing new stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with questions like this is that the answer is always "it depends" however, having recently done some work with Entity Framework and MVC3 I will say that it is a very good platform to work with- MVC3 is logical and easy to work with and EF does a bunch of lifting for you.

Ultimately it depends how far along the project is and how much of it is complete in the way that it currently works. For example, if you have a decently designed database and a bunch of half finished pages then making the switch is probably not going to be a lot harder than finishing up with what you have, but don't underestimate the sheer scale of a rewrite when combined with the need to learn to use several new technologies even if the technologies themselves are fairly quick to learn. On any project of significant size you *will* run into quirks of the platform you are working with and find yourself completely stumped at least a few times.

On the other hand, the idea that something being outdated is a reason to replace working code is one that tends to result in expensive, embarassing project overruns. If it's most of the way finished and you are just lined up to do finishing touches then make the best of what you have and remember that Shipping Is A Feature. Similarly the size of the project and how business critical it is have a big impact. If this is a minor internal project maybe you have more room for a rewrite, if it is responsible for the company's revenue stream you need to get this version out fast and then think about refactoring later.

Either way, you need to talk this over with other stakeholders before throwing yourself into a potentially high-risk endeavour.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the Suggestion. I will have a word with my client on this and make the decision accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have generally used Obout controls as a third party toolkit.  I wish I could help more about switching to ADO.

Although, I don't suppose learning it would hurt, even if you don't end up using it for this particular project.

Good luck!

Comment: I really would like to use some latest usefult technology which helps make the development life easier and make your code more presentable and maintanable. I feel very bad using DataSets as Microsoft has launched so many new things to overcome the bugs of the past. At the same time the project i am working on will continue for next 3-4 years and i really want the client not to be badly dissapointed at the end with us using old technologies with all mess.

Comment: If the project is going to last 3 to 4 years, then even if you use the latest technologies now, there will be something brighter and cooler out in 3 or 4 years so you never catch up.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends... Can you afford to migrate? Is your current framework not what you need it to be?

If you want to throw away 1.5 years of development just because something new has been released, maybe you should think twice. You surely know there's another version of .NET framework coming and who knows what will it bring? Does it mean that you will migrate again next year or so?

However, if you have designed your website the way it can be easily done, by all means, switch to new technologies and migrate how much you want and how you feel comfortable.

Comment: Thanks. I will evaluate and see to find if its feasible to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not it is worth converting your application to EF is a decision only you can make. You know the existing code base better than any of us. Evaluate how much code you would need to change, how much time you have, how much re-testing you would need to do, and so on. Depending on what you find, that will tell you whether you should upgrade or not.

I would love to upgrade every asp.net 2.0 app I find to MVC3 with EF, but usually time and resources only permit that we fix what is broken and move on the next project.

That said, EF is a wonderful advancement in data access. If it isn't worth doing on this project, it is definitely worth learning for the next one.

Comment: Thanks. I will evaluate and see to find if its feasible to migrate.